# Compiling Emacs with Yocto 2.3.2 results in "qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault)"

Tags: emacs, qemu, yocto, bitbake

I have been trying to compile emacs using Bitbake but I encounter the following error in `do_compile` task, which I suspect it is a problem purely related to a bug in `qemu`.

Just to add, I had to recompile a stable version of `icu` to get a proper *.so file, use `EXTRA_OECONF_append = " --with-jpeg=no"` and had to also compile `giflib` and `liblockfile` to come to this point.

Should you need any more information, I'm more than happy to provide.

Here is the error from log file:

```
| qemu-i386  -s 1048576 -L /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/emacs/23.4-r4/qemu-treedir ../lib-src/make-docfile -d /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/emacs/23.4-r4/emacs-23.4/src dosfns.o msdos.o xterm.o xfns.o xmenu.o xselect.o xrdb.o xsmfns.o fringe.o image.o fontset.o dbusbind.o nsterm.o nsfns.o nsmenu.o nsselect.o nsimage.o nsfont.o w32.o w32console.o w32fns.o w32heap.o w32inevt.o w32menu.o w32proc.o w32reg.o w32select.o w32term.o w32xfns.o xfont.o ftfont.o xftfont.o ftxfont.o dispnew.o frame.o scroll.o xdisp.o menu.o xmenu.o window.o charset.o coding.o category.o ccl.o character.o chartab.o cm.o term.o terminal.o xfaces.o xterm.o xfns.o xselect.o xrdb.o fontset.o xsmfns.o fringe.o image.o xsettings.o xgselect.o gtkutil.o dbusbind.o emacs.o keyboard.o macros.o keymap.o sysdep.o buffer.o filelock.o insdel.o marker.o minibuf.o fileio.o dired.o filemode.o cmds.o casetab.o casefiddle.o indent.o search.o regex.o undo.o alloc.o data.o doc.o editfns.o callint.o eval.o floatfns.o fns.o font.o print.o lread.o syntax.o unexelf.o bytecode.o process.o callproc.o region-cache.o sound.o atimer.o doprnt.o strftime.o intervals.o textprop.o composite.o md5.o    xfont.o ftfont.o xftfont.o ftxfont.o > ../etc/DOC
| qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
| qemu-i386: /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.8.0-r0/qemu-2.8.0/translate-all.c:175: tb_lock: Assertion `!have_tb_lock' failed.
| qemu-i386: /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/qemu-native/2.8.0-r0/qemu-2.8.0/translate-all.c:175: tb_lock: Assertion `!have_tb_lock' failed.
| Makefile:135: recipe for target '../etc/DOC' failed
| make[1]: *** [../etc/DOC] Error 127
| make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Segmentation fault (core dumped)
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/emacs/23.4-r4/build/src'
| Makefile:339: recipe for target 'src' failed
| make: *** [src] Error 2
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/emacs/23.4-r4/temp/log.do_compile.558)
ERROR: Task (/home/mozcelikors-host/poky/meta-embeddev/recipes-editors/editors/emacs_23.4.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2087 tasks of which 2051 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

My `conf/bblayers.conf`

```
...
BBLAYERS ?= " \
   /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/meta \
   /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/meta-poky \
   /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
   /home/mozcelikors-host/poky/meta-embeddev \  #Involves emacs
  "
...
```

In `conf/local.conf`, I have

```
MACHINE ??= "qemux86"
```

And here is the `emacs.inc` just in case,

```
DESCRIPTION = "Emacs"
HOMEPAGE = "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/"
LICENSE = "GPLv3"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d32239bcb673463ab874e80d47fae504"
SECTION = "editor"
# and it needs to run some generated binaries..
DEPENDS += " qemu-native"

DEPENDS +=" liblockfile"

X11DEPENDS = " \
    libice libsm atk cairo dbus expat libffi fontconfig freetype gconf giflib \
    jpeg xz pixman libpng librsvg tiff libcroco \
    libx11 libxau libxcomposite libxcursor libxdamage libxdmcp libxext libxfixes \
    libxft libxpm libxrandr libxrender \
    gdk-pixbuf glib-2.0 gtk+ pango libxcb harfbuzz icu \
"

EXTRA_OECONF =  "--without-sound --with-crt-dir=${STAGING_LIBDIR} --with-jpeg=no"

PACKAGECONFIG ??= "${@base_contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11', 'x11', '', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG[x11] = "--with-x-toolkit=gtk,--without-x --without-dbus,${X11DEPENDS}"


inherit autotools

PACKAGES =+ "${PN}-el"

FILES_${PN}-el = "${datadir}/emacs/*/*/*.el.gz \
                  ${datadir}/emacs/*/*/*/*.el.gz"

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/emacs ${datadir}/icons"

FILES_${PN}-dbg += "${libexecdir}/emacs/*/*/.debug ${datadir}/emacs/*/*/.debug"

TREEDIR = "${WORKDIR}/qemu-treedir"

QEMUARCH= "${TARGET_ARCH}"
QEMUARCH_i486 = "i386"
QEMUARCH_i586 = "i386"
QEMUARCH_i686 = "i386"

# Large stack is required at least on x86_64 host, otherwise random segfaults appear:
QEMU = "qemu-${QEMUARCH} ${QEMU_OPTIONS} -s 1048576 -L ${TREEDIR} "

export LOGNAME = "$(whoami)"

do_compile_prepend() {
    sed -i ':1;s:\(START.* \|LIB_STANDARD.* \|LIBES.* \)/usr/lib:\1${STAGING_LIBDIR}:;t1' ${S}/src/s/gnu-linux.h `find "${S}" -name Makefile`
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TARGET_SYS}/lib"
# Ugly hack, see files/use-qemu.patch for more:
    ln -sf ../src/emacs lisp/emacs
    ln -sf ../src/emacs lib-src/emacs
    ln -sf ../src/emacs leim/emacs
#copy STAGING_DIR_TARGET and libgcc_s.so* to WORKDIR/qemu-treedir #copied code from glibc-package.bbclass
    treedir=${TREEDIR}
    if [ -e $treedir ];then
        rm -rf $treedir
    fi

    mkdir -p $treedir/${base_libdir}

    if [ -f ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TARGET_SYS}/${base_libdir}/libgcc_s.so ]; then
        cp -pPR ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TARGET_SYS}/${base_libdir}/libgcc_s.so $treedir/${base_libdir}
    fi
    if [ -f ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TARGET_SYS}/${base_libdir}/libgcc_s.so.* ]; then
        cp -pPR ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/${TARGET_SYS}/${base_libdir}/libgcc_s.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}
    fi
    # stupid hack, but without it, it tries to use /usr/lib/libc.so from host and fails
    # temacs: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libc.so: ELF file version does not match current one
    if [ ! -f $treedir/${base_libdir}/libc.so ]; then
        ln -s libc.so.6 $treedir/${base_libdir}/libc.so
    fi

    # copy only as much stuff as we need
    # before: 5.5G   ../../qemu-treedir/
    # after:   17M   ../../qemu-treedir/
    cp -pPR \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/ld-* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libc.* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libc-* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libm-* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libm.* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libtinfo.so.* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libresolv* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libdl* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/librt* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libgcc_s.so.* \
    ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libpthread* $treedir/${base_libdir}/

    if [ ! -z "${@base_contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'x11', 'x11', '', d)}" ] ; then
        echo "X11 build enabled"
        # copy only as much stuff as we need
        # before: 5.5G   ../../qemu-treedir/
        # after:   86M   ../../qemu-treedir/
        cp -pPR \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libuuid.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${base_libdir}/libz.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libICE.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libSM.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libatk-1.0.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libcairo.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libdbus-1.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libdbus-glib-1.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libexpat.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libffi.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libfontconfig.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libfreetype.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libgconf-2.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libgif.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libjpeg.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/liblzma.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libpixman-1.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libpng1*.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/librsvg-2.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libstdc++.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libtiff.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libxml2.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libcroco-0.6.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libharfbuzz.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libicule.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libicuuc.so.* \
        ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libicudata.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}/

        # X11 Xau Xcomposite Xcursor Xdamage Xdmcp Xext Xfixes Xft Xpm Xrandr Xrender
        cp -pPR ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libX*.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}/

        # gdk-x11 gdk_pixbuf gio glib gmodule gobject gthread gtk-x11
        cp -pPR ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libg*-2.0.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}/

        # pango pangocairo pangoft2
        cp -pPR ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libpango*-1.0.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}/

        # xcb-render xcb-shm xcb
        cp -pPR ${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}/${libdir}/libxcb*.so.* $treedir/${base_libdir}/
    fi
}

do_install_append() {
    # freaks package.bbclass and whole bitbake call returns error code
    # ERROR: runstrip: ''arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-strip'  '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/shr-core-branches/workspace/shr-core/tmp-eglibc/work/armv4t-oe-linux-gnueabi/emacs-23.4-r0/package/usr/share/emacs/23.4/etc/tutorials/TUTORIAL.ko'' strip command failed
    mv ${D}${datadir}/${BPN}/${PV}/etc/tutorials/TUTORIAL.ko ${D}${datadir}/${BPN}/${PV}/etc/tutorials/TUTORIAL.KO
    # Info dir listing isn't interesting at this point so remove it if it exists.
    if [ -e "${D}${infodir}/dir" ]; then
        rm -f ${D}${infodir}/dir
    fi
}

EXTRA_OEMAKE += 'QEMU="${QEMU}"'
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions...

Comment: Where does meta-embeddev come from?  What version of Yocto are you using?

Comment: meta-embeddev is a layer i created to add emacs and many other tools. I use yocto version 2.3.2. I also compile emacs with  x11.

Comment: Are you sure you need to run qemu during do_compile (what's the purpose)? There are several ways to run (native or target) binaries during a build but what you are doing seems very unusual.

Comment: I am not running qemu, just building emacs. However if you say that this emacs.inc file which i obtained from meta-oe does run qemu unusually during do_compile, could you help me get rid of it?

Comment: wow, that really is from meta-oe! It looks so weird that that was hard to believe... Anyway, the emacs recipe was removed from meta-oe soon after 2.3 release because it was broken and unmaintained. I'm sorry I can't really help: that's one very special recipe.

Comment: Wow.. good to know. Also this is the first experiment im doing with bitbake. What are the odds im trying this very unusual recipe 